Chrome Autocomplete
I have these two fields where the autocomplete works perfectly on all cases except  1. When using Chrome and in my production environment it is just switched, username suggests password and current-password suggests email. My development environment works just perfectly on Chrome. What could it be?
I just don't know what to try, because the problem doesn't make any sense.
